# PowerBI Embedded (App Owns Data) Creating embed token with effective identity fails

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, ssas, powerbi-embedded

The error message I get is:

`Creating embed token for accessing dataset <my-data-set-guid> requries effective identity username to be identical to the caller's principal name.`

I am using PowerBI Embedded inside a .NET Core 2.2 Web App with a master account (as opposed to a service principal). Behind the scenes is Azure Active Directory and Azure Analysis Services with Live Connection. I am trying to pass in an effective identity based off the currently logged in user so that their permissions are used for loading the report.

My code is as follows:

```
// In Razor Page Get method
ClaimsPrincipal user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
List<Claim> claims = user.Claims.ToList();
string name = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
string preferredName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;
string roles = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
string upn = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn)?.Value;

var SelectedReport = await _reportRepository.GetReportForIdAsync(reportId.Value, upn, roles);

// In Repository
public async Task<EmbeddedReportConfig> GetReportForIdAsync(Guid reportId, string name, string roles)
{
    try
    {
        AzureToken azureToken = await _authenticationHandler.GetAzureTokenDataAsync();

        using (PowerBIClient powerBiClient = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_powerBiSettings.ApiUrl), azureToken.TokenCredentials))
        {
            Report powerBiReport = await powerBiClient.Reports.GetReportAsync(_powerBiSettings.WorkspaceId, reportId.ToString());

            var rolesList = new List<string>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roles))
            {
                rolesList.AddRange(roles.Split(','));
            }

            List<EffectiveIdentity> rowLevelSecurityIdentity = new List<EffectiveIdentity>
            {
                new EffectiveIdentity(
                    name,
                    roles: rolesList,
                    datasets: new List<string> {powerBiReport.DatasetId}
                )
            };
            GenerateTokenRequest powerBiTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest("View", null, identities: rowLevelSecurityIdentity);

            EmbedToken powerBiTokenResponse = await powerBiClient.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(_powerBiSettings.WorkspaceId, powerBiReport.Id, powerBiTokenRequestParameters);

            return new EmbeddedReportConfig
            {
                ReportId = Guid.Parse(powerBiReport.Id),
                Name = powerBiReport.Name,
                EmbedUrl = powerBiReport.EmbedUrl,
                AccessToken = powerBiTokenResponse.Token
            };
        }
    }
    catch (HttpOperationException ex)
    {
        // https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/quot-shouldn-t-have-effective-identity-quot-error-when-passing/td-p/433730
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security
        //Bad Request
        var content = ex.Response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(content);
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see I pass in the user's UPN for the Effective Identity name. If I sign in as the master user (for embedding) then the request for the token will succeed, but if I use any other account that belongs to the same AAD tenant then it fails with the error message above.

I see that others have run into this issue before [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Azure-Analysis-Services-RLS-and-Embedding/td-p/239127). Using the `CustomData` functionality as mentioned here will not work as not all of the data tables are tagged with the UPN, there are separate roles setup inside Azure Analysis Services.

I noticed some mention of adding UPN mapping ([link1](https://www.cloudfronts.com/analysis-services-connection-configuration-power-bi-live-connection/), [link2](https://guyinacube.com/2016/06/user-principal-name-upn-mapping-in-power-bi/)) but I'm not sure if I can use this because the BI Analyst setup the Data Gateway inside the Azure Portal rather than in the PowerBI portal.

I have tried using the sample [App Owns Data application](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data) but I run into the same issue.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050580/unable-to-generate-embed-token-for-accessing-dataset-due-to-missing-roles-in-eff/56347781#56347781

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is old now but maybe this will help someone.

You need to set the `EffectiveIdentity` `username` property to the service principal object ID as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal#how-to-get-the-service-principal-object-id)