# PowerBI Embed Service Principal embed token generation error for effective ID

Tags: powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I have set up a dedicated PowerBI capacity, added a service principal as an admin to the workspace and am now trying to embed a report that has a direct connection to Azure Analysis Services, authenticating as the service principal.

When I try to issue an embed token, I am getting an error message "Creating embed token for accessing dataset [my dataset id] requries effective identity username to be identical to the caller's principal name"

I am using the PowerBI .NET Core package Microsoft.PowerBI.Api, version 3.14.0 from Nuget to try and issue the code, and this is the code:

```
GenerateTokenRequest generateTokenRequestParameters;
//var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(AppObjectId, new List<string> { report.DatasetId });
var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(ApplicationId, new List<string> { report.DatasetId });
rls.Roles = new string[] { "AllData" };
generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view", 
                                     identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rls });
var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(workspaceId, 
                             report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);
```

Things I have tried:

- Sending the exact same effective ID string as the Service Principal credential (the app id)
- Sending the App Registration Object ID as the effective ID String

Any ideas to help me troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This very brief answer had the key point in it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59026502/139200 (the linked article does *not* answer this question)

The important point is that you should get the Id value of the ServicePrincipal object in AAD, and not the object ID of the app registration.

To get the ServicePrincipal id, use the Az PowerShell module and run  Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId your-application-id

The output will contain a field called "Id", that is what you need to pass as the effective identity:
[image: Screenshot of a Get-AzAdServicePrincipal command]

Comment: That's insane! Don't understand me wrong. Your soulution works. But how the hell could I know it? Where in AAD can I find this Id? Can I set it? Is there any docs which directly say to do so?